# How do i add reference to Visual Basic power packs in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have installed Visual Basic Power packs package and want to reference the VisualBasic.PowerPacks dll but it is not visible. Using VS 2012 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy way to reference a `dll` is:

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project.
2. On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
      The Add Reference dialog box opens.
3. Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference. In your case, you will have to select **COM** tab.

An [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwawt96c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on **MSDN** to include installed libraries.

Comment: In COM tab, it is not visible.

Comment: There are many tabs, I've not used this pack so I am not sure where will it be. You have to search in all tabs. It must be there.

Comment: Big thanks for your comment "got it". Also searching for it... some hint where it is would be useful. -.-

Answer (score 3):

The DLL is located here:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 Power Packs\3.0`

DLL Name: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll`

[Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-add-references-to-type-libraries) to add reference:

1. Right-click References
2. Click Add Reference
3. Click Browse at the bottom
4. Select the DLL file.