# How To Properly Install Visual Basic Power Packs in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, powerpacks

Regarding installing and using Visual Basic Power Packs to be used with a C# application, I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366866/how-do-i-add-reference-to-visual-basic-power-packs-in-windows-form-c-sharp) and another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322344/vb-net-visual-basic-power-packs-not-working-on-vs2015), which said I don't need to add a reference. (This did not make sense to me.)

I have downloaded the separate installation program for Visual Basic Power Packs and installed successfully.

However, I cannot reference them inside Visual Studio. They're checked off and part of the Toolbox, though.

I would appreciate help in what to do next.

Comment: Are they in the toolbox? Can you drag in controls from the toolbox? Do they work?

Comment: @mjwills This is the answer. The controls are there, but how do I reference them? They are no longer a reference.

Comment: @mjwills You drag them in from the tool box.